# Create docker image of project that uses yarn link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js, yarnpkg

In my NextJS project I use yarn as the package manager and decided to use [yarn link](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/) to have import aliases/absolute imports. This is a neat feature of yarn and the recommended way to use aliases if you use yarn. However, after I implemented it, my docker image creation script broke. The image creation fails on step 6, which is the actual build. Everything works beautifuly if I run `yarn dev` or `yarn build`, but docker doesn't seem to undertand I'm using aliases. Here's the script I ran the the outputs:

Scripts: `docker build --pull --rm -f dockerfile -t my-ui .  && docker run -d --name my-ui -p 80:80 my-ui`

Outsputs:

```
 => CACHED [builder 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:10-alpine@sha256:dc98dac24efd4254f75976c40bce46944697a110d06ce7fa47e726847  0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                4.7s 
 => => transferring context: 2.46MB                                                                                              4.6s 
 => [builder 2/6] COPY package.json yarn.lock ./                                                                                 0.1s 
 => [builder 3/6] RUN yarn install --ignore-engines && mkdir /my-ui && mv ./node_modules ./my-ui               364.1s 
 => [builder 4/6] WORKDIR /my-ui                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [builder 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                      15.2s 
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] RUN yarn run build
```

The error I get is the following: `Type error: Cannot find module 'style/icons/More' or its corresponding type declarations.`

This occurs right in the first component of the project. I searched and found nothing on yarn-link and docker. How do I make docker understand that `style/*` is an alias and be able to find the corresponding modules?

Comment: `yarn link` is meant for development use, not for production packaging (such as what you're doing).

Comment: @AKX, thanks for the info. I did not know that. In this case, how to proceed? For me it makes no sense to have a framework for aliases that works only for development and affect production build.

Comment: The [docs for `yarn link` tell you what it's for](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/). Either way, the (link-only) answer below might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using `yarn link` in this case as it should be used for development only and instead, you can use `webpack` alias.
https://teselagen.com/blog/a-better-alternative-to-npm-yarn-link-for-front-end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).